# Individual image prediciton in Tensorflow different than batch evaluate

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, prediction

I'm using Tensorflow v2.4.1 to try and train a CNN. Here is a (simplified) version of my training:

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
      rescale=1./255,
      zca_epsilon=1e-06,
      rotation_range=20,
      width_shift_range=.2,
      height_shift_range=.2,
      shear_range=0.2,
      zoom_range=.2,
      fill_mode='nearest',
      cval=0.,  # value used for fill_mode = "constant")


train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
  data_dir + '/train',
  target_size=(256,256),
  batch_size=64,
  class_mode='categorical'
)

model.fit(train_generator)
```

Now, I am trying to write some code that will test the model on a similarly structured directory of images, one-by-one. I'm doing this like so:

```
class_list = ['a','b','c','d']
count_total = 0
count_right = 0
for c in class_list:
    test_dir = data_dir + '/test/', + c + '/'
    for imagepath in os.listdir(test_dir):
        image = cv2.imread(test_dir+imagepath)
        image_from_array = Image.fromarray(image, "RGB")
        size_image = image_from_array.resize((256,256))
        p = np.expand_dims(size_image, 0)
        img = tf.cast(p, tf.float32)/255
        pred = class_list[np.argmax(model.predict(img))]
        count_total += 1
        if pred == c:
            count_right += 1
acc = count_right/count_total
```

My accuracy(`acc`) is coming out to be 0.20. However, I think this is a problem with the code, rather than the proper accuracy, because if I run the below code:

```
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    data_dir + '/test',
    target_size=(256,256),
    batch_size=64,
    class_mode='categorical'
  )

model.evaluate(test_generator)
```

Then `model.evaluate()` reports an accuracy of 0.53

So what is wrong with the code that predicts images one-by-one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opencv loads images by default in BGR while TensorFlow uses RGB. The images you are predicting are significantly different from the one you trained the network with, resulting in a loss of accuracy.

After loading your image with opencv, you should convert it to RGB, or use pillow directly to load the image in RGB.

**Converting from BGR to RGB in opencv:**

```
img_bgr = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

**Reading the image directly with Pillow in RGB**

```
img = Image.open("/path/to/the/image")
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I didn't realize I wasn't already doing this